# Desabilitar Textarea (com TinyMCE) ao carregar dado do mysql

Tags: php, javascript

Para desabilitar um textarea com o tinyMCE eu usava o código

```
tinyMCE.get('id_textarea').getBody().setAttribute('contenteditable', false);
```

dentro de um script Javascript, com evento onclick de um button, e ocorria tudo bem.

O problema agora é o seguinte: tenho 5 páginas, cada página com 5 textareas, todos editáveis pelo tinyMCE, e com um botão "Salvar" para cada textarea. Na última página, inseri um botão submit "Enviar", o qual grava um "sim" no BD mysql, numa tabela com os textarea e com o campo "enviado" que recebe esse "sim". O que estou tentando fazer e não consigo, é, após clicar nesse botão submit "Enviar", que todos os textarea fiquem desabilitados para edição, através de uma consulta SQL ao campo "enviado", ou seja, após gravado o "sim", o usuário não consegue editar mais os textarea, nem naquele momento, nem depois ao reabrir as páginas com textarea.

Já inseri o script na tag `<head>`, já tentei colocar o script num echo dentro do php, e nada adiantou para desabilitar, apenas grava o sim no BD. Segue o código do script e do php/html. Dentro da tag `<head>`:

```
function enviartudo() {            
  tinyMCE.get('id_textarea1').getBody().setAttribute('contenteditable', false);            
  tinyMCE.get('id_textarea2').getBody().setAttribute('contenteditable', false);
}
```

#### PHP

Após um SELECT ao BD:

```
include_once('conexao.php');
$query = "SELECT..........";
$data = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($data);
if ($row['enviado'] == 'sim') {
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">
             enviartudo();
          </script>';
}

if (isset($_POST['enviar'])) {
    $query1 = "UPDATE tabela SET enviado = 'sim' ";
    $data1 = mysqli_query($dbc, $query1);
    mysqli_close($dbc);
 }
```

#### HTML

```
<tr>
    <td>
       <label>TEXTAREA 1</label>
       <textarea type="text" id="textarea1" name="textarea1" class="areatexto"
       maxlength="5000">
          <?php echo (isset($_POST['textarea1']) ? $_POST['textarea1'] : 
          htmlspecialchars_decode(stripslashes($row['textarea1']))); ?>
       </textarea>
       <input type="submit" name="submit1-1" value="Salvar" class="btn_save_item"/>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><br />
       <label>TEXTAREA 2</label>
       <textarea type="text" id="textarea2" name="textarea2" class="areatexto" maxlength="8000">
          <?php echo (isset($_POST['textarea2']) ? $_POST['textarea2'] : 
          htmlspecialchars_decode(stripslashes($row['textarea2']))); ?>
       </textarea>
       <input type="submit" name="submit1-2" value="Salvar" class="btn_save_item" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>
      <input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Enviar" class="btn_save_item" />
   </td>
</tr>
```

Não coloquei todo o código das 5 páginas com os 5 textarea de cada uma, pois ficaria muito grande, porém o código é repetitivo, alterando apenas id/name das div, form, textarea, botões submit, entre outros.

Comment: `if ($row['enviado'] == 'sim') { $desabilitado = "disabled";` e nos textareas `<textarea type="text" ..... maxlength="5000" <?php echo $desabilitado ?>>`

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo, já havia tentado isso, mas o tinymce não aceita o "disabled", nem o "readonly" no textarea. Se coloco readonly:1 no Setup do tinymce, todos os textarea já iniciam em readonly ao carregar, e não é isso o que desejo. De qq forma, valeu, mas o problema continua..

Comment: Pessoal, encontrei uma solução. Criei outro script do tinymce, porém alterando o nome do Selector e com outro skin (para alterar o background do textarea), além de inserir o readonly=1. Aí, no PHP, fiz um if/else, criando uma variável que define a classe do textarea. E no código HTML, no textarea, inseri uma classe com PHP: `class="<?php echo $variavel; ?>"` . Vou por a solução abaixo..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conforme comentei acima, após uma boa noite de sono encontrei uma solução.

Criei outro script do tinymce, porém alterei o nome do Selector e inseri o readonly=1, menubar=false e deixei só o preview na toolbar, tudo para não permitir mais qq edição. Criei tb outro skin (para alterar o background do textarea). No PHP, fiz um if/else, criando uma variável que define a classe dos textarea. E no código HTML, nos textarea, inseri uma classe com PHP. Seguem os códigos:

Script 1 do tinymce:

```
tinymce.init ({
        selector: '.areatexto',
        height: 200,
        skin: 'custom',
        theme: 'modern',
        resize: false,
        plugins: 'print charwordcount preview searchreplace autolink visualblocks visualchars image link media table charmap hr pagebreak nonbreaking anchor insertdatetime advlist lists textcolor imagetools contextmenu colorpicker textpattern',
        toolbar1: 'formatselect | bold italic strikethrough forecolor backcolor | link | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify  | numlist bullist outdent indent  | removeformat | table image | preview',});
```

Criei outro script do tinymce:

```
tinymce.init ({
        selector: '.areatexto2', //aplica o plugin em todos textarea com class="areatexto2"
        height: 200, //altura de cada textarea
        skin: 'custom2',
        theme: 'modern',
        readonly: 1,
        resize: false,
        plugins: 'preview',
        toolbar1: 'preview',
        menubar: false, });
```

Criei um if/else no PHP:

`if ($row['enviado'] == 'sim') {
    $classTextarea = "areatexto2";
}
else {
     $classTextarea = "areatexto";
}`

E no HTML:

`<textarea type="text" id="xxxxxx" name="xxxxx" class="<?php echo $classTextarea; ?>" maxlength="5000">`

Funciona perfeitamente, não permitindo mais a edição dos textarea (com class="areatexto2"), pois o readonly=1, além de retirar o menubar e todos plugins de edição.